# PySpark DataFrame keeps converting time column to timestamp

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a table from PostgreSQL. The table contains a column `elap_time` whose `datatype` is `time`. But when reading into spark `DataFrame` it automatically converts it to `timestamp`. How to avoid this.

```
config = {"fs.gs.impl": "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem",
           "fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl": "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS"
           }

conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
for (name, value) in config.items():
      conf.set(name, value)

source = {
        "url": url,
        'user': user,
        'database': db,
        'password': pass,
        'port': '5432',
        'driver': 'org.postgresql.Driver',
        'dbtable': 'newtable'
    }
spark.read.format("JDBC").options(**source).load()
df.printSchema()
```

this is the output:

```
#|-- elap_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

This is the actual data in the Database

```
+-------------------+                                                           
|         elap_time |
+-------------------+
|08:02:19           |
|08:02:19           |
+-------------------+
```

This is the output of spark dataframe

```
+-------------------+                                                           
|          elap_time|
+-------------------+
|1970-01-01 08:02:19|
|1970-01-01 08:02:19|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Can you share sample from your input data and its expected output?

Comment: @DKNY this is the actual data
|08:02:19|
|08:02:19|
This is the output in spark
+-------------------+                                                           
|         elap_time|
+-------------------+
|1970-01-01 08:02:19|
|1970-01-01 08:02:19|
+-------------------+

Comment: Please add this to your post.

Comment: Someone has suggested an EDIT and it is yet to be approved. I am unable to edit my post...

Comment: Ahh I see. Once, your `dataframe` is created, add a new column using `withColumn` and then parse the original time as `date_format(to_timestamp(<Your time column>), "HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: @DKNY That would create a new column. The major issue I am facing is that I cannot write to bigquery with a column of datatype timestamp but values of time. It is throwing  invalid timestamp error.

Comment: You can replace the original column by the newly created column. I know this is kinda workaround, but I can't think of any alternative solution as of now.

Comment: there is no Time type in spark (see official documentation : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.types). Spark is simply using the only way it has to store the data from your DB which is timestamp (with the date included). If you want only "time" that'd be a string type for formated value or a int type for time in seconds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by user [DKNY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15112563/dkny) in comment section. "your dataframe is created, add a new column using withColumn and then parse the original time as date_format(to_timestamp(), "HH:mm:ss"). You can replace the original column by the newly created column. I know this is kinda workaround, but I can't think of any alternative solution as of now."

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

df = df.withColumn('date', date_format('date', 'HH:mm:ss'))
df.show()
```